# SharePoint 2016 SSO with Custom Web API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, spfx-webparts

I am trying to Build SSO between SharePoint 2016 On Premise site and Custom Web API which is hosted in On Premise IIS.

I tired to build a Provider Hosted Add In to achieve this. But It seems not behaving like a typical web API. ( Meaning providing a JSON result over REST)

Again I tried to install **AppForSharePoint16WebToolkit** for my Custom Web API. I searched in the internet but I was unable to find a proper solution to identify how SharePoint SSO works with Web API. Meaning I want to Secure my Web API aligning with SharePoint. (i.e. User does not required to Sign In again)

This requirement is a must. Any Idea will be a big help for me. Thanks